# Couch DB 1.5 & The NodeJS Query Server

Tags: performance, node.js, erlang, view, couchdb

I've recently noticed that Couch DB is back in heavy development. One of the more interesting features to have been added in the last iteration (https://blogs.apache.org/couchdb/entry/apache_couchdb_1_5_0) is a NodeJS query server.

As the default Spidermonkey query server is known to be notoriously slow under mid/heavy loads, I was wondering if anyone knows what kind of performance benefit can be achieved with the Nodejs server, and how it might compare to writing views directly in Erlang.

Anyone have any experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience, but since CouchDB is built in erlang I feel any other query servers would be slower because of the interface tasking between core and others. Still I think we should have facts to prove it I have read quite

May be this gives you some idea.. and I nerd on NodeJS on this

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Performance#View_generation